# Automatically publish a NuGet package built with VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, .net-standard

New in Visual Studio 2017 is the ability to generate a NuGet package on build for some target types (namely, `.NET Standard 2.0` which is what I'm using).

This works great, and the `.nupkg` file is generated on successful build.

However, I'm not able to figure out how to get the built package automatically published to our local repository.

I already tried a post-build event of:

```
nuget push -Source https://my.nuget.server/nuget/ "C:\Source\MyProject\bin\Release\MyProject.1.0.0.nupkg"
```

But this presents 2 problems:

1. The name of the package includes the version number and this isn't available as a post-build event variable, so I can't say, for example, `nuget push $(NugetPackage)`. I also can't figure out a combination of macros/variables that would get me the package name effectively.
2. The automatic NuGet packaging process occurs *after the post-build event*, so at the time of post-build, the package has not even been generated yet!

Microsoft has provided this kick-ass automatic NuGet packaging, but no way to push it to a local repository (or so it seems)!

Has anyone gotten this to work? Am I missing something? Is there a workaround? Is this something being worked on?

Answer (score 15):

You can automate a publish to nuget by adding the below line to your libraries *csproj* directly. You will need to either set an environment variable to the location of your nuget.exe, add the location to your system's PATH, or hard enter it into the `Command` parameter.

Personally, I prefer to download the [latest version of nuget.exe](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe) and place it into the user's `%userprofile%\.nuget` folder. This is where nuget stores the local cache of packages, so it should be already created.

Example of publishing to a remote repository.

```
<Target Name="PostPackNugetDeploy" AfterTargets="Pack" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <Exec Command="="%userprofile%\.nuget\nuget.exe push &quot;$(OutputPath)$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg&quot; -Source &quot;$(NuGetSourceRelease)&quot; -Verbosity Detailed" />
</Target>
```

Example of publishing to a local repository.

```
<Target Name="PostPackNugetDeploy" AfterTargets="Pack" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
 <Exec Command="%userprofile%\.nuget\nuget.exe add &quot;$(OutputPath)$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg&quot; -source \\Server\Packages" />
</Target>
```

You can find the docs on the MSBuild targets for nuget here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets

### Update

I have wrapped this into a nuget package that can be referenced within your project. It takes care of all this, all you have to do is add a property to your project.

You can fine the code and full guide here.
https://github.com/SimplerSoftware/SS.NuGet.Publish

Comment: Worked for me, but I used a "copy" command instead of the "exec" command: `<Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)..\$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg" DestinationFolder="\\networkshare\folder" />`

Comment: That doesn't publish it, it copies the file. If you publish it, it will create folder structure for versioning.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am new to nuget, so I will try the "add" command to compare.

Comment: John is right. After changing it to exec nuget, a folder representing the version, an sha file and a nuspec file all appeared in the Nuget Feed Repository.

Answer (score 3):

This feature has been requested here: [Enable push from VS](https://github.com/nuget/home/issues/4459).

NuGet publish is generally handled using build/deployment automation software like TFS, VSTS, Jenkins, etc.

Comment: Thanks - I added a comment to that feature request to track it. Seems like there are some other folks that need this as well - not everyone has a fully-featured ALM set up, some of us like to publish right from VS because it's quick and frictionless. :)