# Visual Studio 2017 push nuget to (internal) nuget server

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget, msbuild-task

I am drowning in nuget repostories (20+ nugets) and I can build and pack a nuget via Visual Studio 2017. Thats pretty and fine.

What I am missing is the last mile pushing the nuget to the server.

To do this I have to go to the projects \src\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish directory, open a command line and type in the f.. command to push the nuget to the server.

That doesn't feel like the 3rd century.

Anyway to automate this?

I understand I have a special use case (during my current development step) which will be obsolete later. Currently I a converting existing codes to nugets and I don't want to increment version numbers during the multiple builds unitl the first version is ready and until the first version isn't ready we don't use a CI / build server and I have to build the nugets locally.

This involves the problem that building a new nuget package (with new code) but the same version leaves the old code (under the same version number) in the local nuget caches. Therefor I have to clean the nuget caches (and reload them which one should do only if a nuget caching server is used or a high network traffic will be the result).

---

The best way I figured out so far was utilizing MSBuild targets.

I came so far:

```
  <Target Name="DeployReleaseNuget" AfterTargets="Pack" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <Exec Command="nuget locals all -clear"></Exec>
    <Exec Command="nuget push -Source http://debug.our-nuget.server/v3/index.json &quot;$(OutputPath)publish\$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg&quot;" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="DeployReleaseNuget" AfterTargets="Pack" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Exec Command="nuget locals all -clear"></Exec>
    <Exec Command="nuget push -Source http://release.our-nuget-server/v3/index.json &quot;$(OutputPath)publish\$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

This seems to work so far, I just can't figure out how to tie the target to a specific publish profile (which I named 'TestProfile'). It seems there is no variable for the profile name? So far each build (even on the build server just using the command line to build triggers the upload, which is unintended.

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for? Usually this kind of job is handled by CI server; TeamCity, Jenkins etc.

Comment: Well, I would accept anything that prevents me from typing the command line each time. Can I create a publish profile "extension" doing this for me? Sure, it will be done by CI but currently we are migrating to nugets and to CI and for now I have to do this manually.

Comment: How about something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50279958/7225096

Comment: looks complicated :( will have a close look into it tommorow

Comment: seems to roughly work and I already in love with you. Any last hints?

Comment: Hi, (since I need to replace them): Do you mean "Update"?

Comment: ahm, if update is able to replace one version 0.1.0 with another version 0.1.0. I am currently migrating an code base from about 5 shared projects to 20+ nugets. Until thr migration is done I don't want to increase the version number for every new version (inbetween). Once the migration is done and the CI does the builds each build get a new version and i don't need to replace them in local nuget caches an on the nuget server.

Comment: What do you mean specific publish profile? .nuspec file?

Comment: To delete them, you need to use [nuget delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-delete), I've checked that the `nuget add command` won't replace a same-name fodler no matter you have a same or higher nuget package version. So you can add a `<Exec command="nuget delete ..." condition="Exists(...)"/>` before the nuget add command.